# Complex numbers modulus algebra help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$$ \xi_{\pm} =  ip\sin(w) \pm i\sqrt{p^2\sin^2 w-1}$$

if i take the modulus of this complex number what will I get?

is it

$$ ( ip\sin w \pm  i\sqrt{p^2 \sin^2 w-1}) ( -ip\sin w\pm -i\sqrt{p^2\sin^2 w-1}) \text{ ?}$$

and also can someone show me the modulus of this number

$$  ip\sin w \pm  i\sqrt{1-p^2\sin^2 w}$$

the answer is $1,$ but not sure how to get this cause of the plus and minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** If $x\in \Bbb R$ then $|ix|=|x|$.

Comment: so you just ignore the i ? so it would be $ | psin(w) \pm \sqrt{p^{2}sin^{2}(w)-1}|$ so you dont multiply by its conjugate?

Comment: @Italy Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: okay thanks, can you also help me with the seoncd one? the modulus of it?